# Okay method to aggregate moving averages?

Tags: methodology, aggregation, moving-average

I want to make a map of investments in foreign countries made by country x. I have collected data for a ten-year period. Since investments change from year to year and there's lack of data for some countries, I thought that I would aggregate moving averages of this period of time, and then map this. I am a statistics novice, and don't know whether this is a robust method? If so, which method do I ultimately use to aggregated the moving averages?

Many thanks!

Comment: Really not clear at all. Lack of data for some countries: understood, but are you trying to impute missing values? Aggregate moving averages: what does this mean? Just averaging or totalling over a period is simpler and easier to understand and explain. Robust: in what sense? How does wanting a map affect the question? How many numbers would you map for each country? It seems as if you are trying to summarise an entire project in one paragraph and expecting us to understand everything.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. I'm not trying to impute missing values. Since I want to create one world map (not several for different years, i.e. I want one number for each country), I need one column of data to import into GIS. Either I make the map according to one specific year, or I total or average the data for the different years into one number. However, this will misrepresent the countries that lack data for some years. That's why I thought of going for the moving averages, and then to add these up somehow, but I don't know how to go about. Don't know if this makes things clearer.

Comment: That helps; thanks. Moving averages won't help with missing values. If this were my problem I would use some interpolation method (e.g. piecewise cubic Hermite) to do what I could with gaps and then average over the period of record. As a geographer I regard mapping amounts by countries as a fairly lousy representation (!) (e.g. can you identify amounts for Bahrain, Qatar, UAE easily on a world map?) but a positive for you is that most readers will presumably want an overall impression, not to focus on precise amounts.

Comment: Many thanks, Nick! You're right, I want to show an overall spatial distribution rather than point to the amounts of certain countries.